# WordPress ReCaptcha v1 Login Error

Tags: wordpress, authentication, recaptcha

I have a bit of an issue. When I try to login to my WordPress admin I cannot proceed past this screen. Someone on my old host set up a ReCaptcha login. I'm not sure how they did it. I've looked through the plugins and haven't found anything. I believe it was done through the previous host. I have access to the MySQL database and MyPHPadmin, but I cannot find anything that is referencing this script. Any help would be much appreciated.

http://patchleishman.com/wp-login

Comment: Did you contact your hosting company for support?  Anything in the functions.php file that points to how the are hijacking the login prompt?

Comment: I did contact my host but they said they couldn't find anything and I needed to contact Google. I will look into the functions.php file and see.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the functions.php file that indicates any recaptcha implementation.

Comment: Use notepad++ to search the entire codebase for the word captcha or any other render html elements, css classes, etc that show up on that login page.